# Hook after click save button in product page

Tags: prestashop-1.7

On Prestashop 1.7.5, when I save a product page, it take more than 1 minute which it's a bit long.

I try with a fresh install of PS, and the saving is very fast.
So I guess it's because a module link to the hook.

Which hook is call when we click on "save" button in the product page?
Is it only "actionProductSave"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the hooks that could intervene, knowing that the last 4 are the most commonly used:

```
actionAdminProductsControllerCoreSaveAfter
actionAdminProductsControllerSaveAfter
actionObjectProductAddAfter
actionObjectProductDeleteAfter
actionObjectProductUpdateAfter
actionObjectUpdateAfter
actionProductAdd
actionProductDelete
actionProductSave
actionProductUpdate
```

Regards